# Powershell custom date and time in search

Tags: powershell, date, search

Newbie PS Question - Revising question as I think I am about 95% to my solution based on community help so far.

My PS script is querying a .log file and if it matches a -15 minute rule as well as a text selection, it pulls all of the records I want.  Which is fantastic.

The issue I have is that I need to email the results to me if those conditions are met.  As you can see in the code below, i have the mail setup, but when it comes to the body of the email I get no data.  I have tried setting Body = $body but it breaks.  Any suggestions on how to get this sorted?

Current Code:

```
$qtime = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15) -Format 'yyyyMMddHHmm'
$srch = [regex]::Escape('Licensing: no speech license available for the feature')
$SEL = Select-String -Path C:\ProgramData\Nuance\Enterprise\system\diagnosticLogs\nrs.log -Pattern "Licensing: no speech license available for the feature"
 
if ($SEL -ne $null)
{
 $body =  Get-Content C:\ProgramData\Nuance\Enterprise\system\diagnosticLogs\nrs.log | Where  { $_ -gt $qtime -and $_ -match $srch}
    #    Send-MailMessage -From 'me@domain.com' -To  'me@domain.com' -Subject 'TTS License Error Detected on ServerA' -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com' -body $body
}
else
{
    ## Do Nothing
}
```

Thanks in advance -

J

Comment: take a look at the `[datetime]::ParseExact()` method. [*grin*]

Comment: I realize i have the mail command commented out.  I am just running it that way for the time being to get my result set.

Comment: what on earth does the mail command have to do with parsing the date string you were talking about ... or with the parse method i indicated?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* try to extract the first 14 characters of each line and parse them as a `[datetime]` value, but you don't actually need to do that.

Big-endian date formats (like your `YYYYMMddHHmmss` format for example), are *alphabetically* ordered - that is, if one date predates another, it will also precede it when sorted alphabetically.

That means we can just use a date/time string of the same format, describing the cutoff date, and then compare the lines from the log file to that:

```
$since = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddYears(-4) -Format 'YYYYMMdd'

# this will only return the last 4 years worth of logs
Get-Content old.log | Where { $_ -gt $since }
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  I am able to successfully set the date just fine and subtract the 15 needed minutes.

my PS script is using a Select-String command with a -Pattern of "xyz".  Do I need to look at a different syntax for the | Where as it is currently not liking that.  Or am I supposed to add something in to replace the $_ as my datetime in the logfile?  Apologies in advance, day 1 with powershell...

Comment: @JohnEllis Please add the code you already have [to your existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65691205/edit) :-)